# SQL: extract id who exist for all other pk-columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple database table. I am using VS 2019 and SQL Server.

How do I extract the `maintenance_id` that exists for all `cage_serial_number`?
i.e cleaned all the cages.

`CAGE_SERIAL_NUMBER` is PK for table `CAGE`.

Table: `CAGE`

```
SERIAL_NUMBER
---------------
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
```

Table: `CAGE_CLEANING`

```
MAINTENANCE_ID  | CAGE_SERIAL_NUMBER_PK
----------------+-----------------------
235451026       |   1003
240054289       |   1007
300215485       |   1001
300215485       |   1003
300215485       |   1004
300215485       |   1007
300254987       |   1001
300254987       |   1002
300254987       |   1003
300254987       |   1004
300254987       |   1005
300254987       |   1006
355620125       |   1005
```

Comment: Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: since I have non-experience,  **Gordon Linoff**'s was easier for me to understand.

**Thank** for your help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation and counting:

```
select MAINTENANCE_ID
from CAGE_CLEANING
group by MAINTENANCE_ID
having count(distinct CAGE_SERIAL_NUMBER_PK) = (select count(*) from CAGE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do aggregation :

```
select cc.MAINTENANCE_ID
from CAGE_CLEANING cc
group by cc.MAINTENANCE_ID
having count(distinct CAGE_SERIAL_NUMBER_PK) = (select count(*) from CAGE);
```

You can do join for exact `serial no`s:

```
select cc.MAINTENANCE_ID
from CAGE_CLEANING cc inner join
     CAGE cg
     on cg.SERIAL_NUMBER = cc.CAGE_SERIAL_NUMBER_PK
group by cc.MAINTENANCE_ID
having count(distinct cc.CAGE_SERIAL_NUMBER_PK) = (select count(*) from CAGE);
```